# Работа с PhpStorm c нескольких мест

Tags: phpstorm

Начал работать с PHpStorm. Работаю на локальном компьютере с автоматической загрузкой на удаленный сервер. При открытом проекте соответственно при внесении изменений на локалке все автоматически синхронизируется с удаленным. То же на другом компьютере - на ноутбуке  в поездках.
В какой то этап времени все данные на ПК и ноутбуке были одинаковыми. Далее работа за ПК, изменение файлов проекта, синхрозиация.
Уехал с рабочим ноутом, на котором осталась старая версия проекта, не измененная.
Как теперь продолжить работать с проектом с ноута. При открытии проекта я так понимаю он зальет все старые версии файлов на удаленный сервер?

Comment: А что мешает скопировать файлы с удалённого сервера к себе локально, перед тем как ваш ноутбук"зальёт" что-то туда? Это если топорно. Я полагаю, у вас git не в теме.

Comment: Да, через git, понимаю, что возможно, загрузив на локальный компьютер через git все обновления. Так дольше просто, нет ли возможности делать все это средствами phpstorm, т.е. за основу что бы он брал не локальную версию, а версию удаленного сервера и, при открытии phpstorm на ноутбуке подгружал версию с удаленного сервера, минуя phpstorm?

Comment: Пять раз прочитал — ничего не понял))

Comment: Git — наше всё)